# JavaFX Switching BorderPane's Center: Buttons only work once

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm a tad confused with JavaFX at the minute. Basically, when I run my code, I can only click on a button on the side bar of the application once, then it will swap the center pane for the one that I want displayed. After that though, it appears that the ActionEvent does not trigger... I've tried reattaching them after handling but it doesn't work, and I have no idea whats wrong.

I've spent 2 days trying to crack this, and I'm sure it's something so annoyingly simple.

Controller:

```
@FXML private Button fooButton, barButton;
@FXML private Pane fooPane, barPane;
@FXML private BorderPane mainWindow;
@FXML private TabPane tabPane;
@FXML private VBox buttonBar;
@FXML private AnchorPane centerAP;
private HashMap<Button, Pane> buttonsPaneHMap = new HashMap<>(); //storing the data in a HashMap to create a link between buttons and their panes.

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    putNodesInHashmap();
    assertControlsExist();
    mainWindow.setCenter(welcomePane);
    setOnActions(buttonsPaneHMap);  
}

public final void handleButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Node newCenter = new AnchorPane();

    if (event.getSource() ==  fooButton){
        newCenter = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FXML/fooPane.fxml"));
    }   
    if (event.getSource() ==  barButton){
        newCenter = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FXML/barPane.fxml"));
    }               

    try{
        this.mainWindow.setCenter(newCenter); 
     }
     catch (NullPointerException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }   
 }

public final void setOnActions(HashMap<Button, Pane> hMap){
    for (Button button : hMap.keySet()){
        ((ButtonBase) button).setOnAction(arg0 -> {
            try {
                handleButton(arg0);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }       
}
public final void putNodesInHashMap(){
     buttonsPaneHMap.put(fooButton, fooPane);
     buttonsPaneHMap.put(barButton, barPane);

}
```

FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane fx:id="mainWindow" prefHeight="461.0" prefWidth="760.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="guiControllers.MainController">
   <top>
      <Pane id="body" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="658.0" style="-fx-background-color: #243242; -fx-border-color: #0E141B; -fx-border-radius: 3;" stylesheets="@application.css" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="103.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="48.0" prefWidth="394.0" text="Title Here" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Calibri Bold" size="41.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <ImageView fitHeight="55.0" fitWidth="61.0" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="20.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../Res/mhlogo.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </top>
   <left>
      <VBox id="buttonBar" fx:id="buttonBar" alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="365.0" prefWidth="168.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2E4055; -fx-border-radius: 3; -fx-border-color: #0E141B;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Pane prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="98.0">
               <children>
                  <Pane layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="-2.0" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="169.0" style="-fx-background-color: #565656; -fx-border-color: #000000; -fx-border-radius: 20; -fx-background-radius: 20;">
                     <children>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="19.0" fitWidth="18.0" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="7.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../Res/magnifying-glass.png" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <TextField layoutX="29.0" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="134.0" style="-fx-border-radius: 1; -fx-border-color: #111111; -fx-border-width: 2; -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF; -fx-background-radius: 20; -fx-border-radius: 20;" styleClass="stop-color-leaking" stylesheets="@../cSS/application.css" />
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
               </children>
            </Pane>
            <Button id="fooButton" fx:id="fooButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButton" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="171.0" style="-fx-background-color: #CDCDCD; -fx-border-color: #0E141B; -fx-border-radius: 3;" text="foo" />
            <Button id="barButton" fx:id="barButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButton" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="202.0" style="-fx-background-color: #CDCDCD; -fx-border-color: #0E141B; -fx-border-radius: 3;" text="bar" />

               <children>
                  <ImageView id="settingsButton" fitHeight="38.0" fitWidth="48.0" layoutX="64.0" layoutY="130.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../Res/settings.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </left>
   <right>
      <TabPane id="tabPane" fx:id="tabPane" focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="365.0" prefWidth="166.0" rotateGraphic="true" style="-fx-background-color: # #414760;" styleClass="tab-header-background" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <tabs>
          <Tab fx:id="notesTab" text="Notes">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="336.0" prefWidth="216.0" style="-fx-border-color: #414760; -fx-background-radius: 3;" styleClass="tab-header-background" stylesheets="@../application/CSS/application.css" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab fx:id="diagramTab" closable="false" text="Diagram" />
        </tabs>
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
         </cursor>
         <stylesheets>
            <URL value="@application.css" />
            <URL value="@../application/CSS/application.css" />
         </stylesheets>
      </TabPane>
   </right>
   <center>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="centerAP" style="-fx-background-color: #414760;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <VBox fx:id="welcomePane" prefHeight="304.0" prefWidth="391.0" style="-fx-background-color: #414760;">
               <children>
                  <Pane fx:id="welcomePane" prefHeight="313.0" prefWidth="428.0" style="-fx-background-color: #414760;">
                     <children>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="183.0" fitWidth="296.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="65.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                           <image>
                              <Image url="@../Res/welcomepane.png" />
                           </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <Label layoutX="141.0" layoutY="14.0" text="Welcome" textFill="WHITE">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Calibri Bold" size="33.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Label layoutX="82.0" layoutY="53.0" prefHeight="68.0" prefWidth="346.0" text="To start, please select an" textFill="WHITE" textOverrun="CLIP">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Calibri" size="24.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Label layoutX="82.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="68.0" prefWidth="346.0" text="option from the left." textFill="WHITE" textOverrun="CLIP">
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Calibri" size="24.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

As far as I can tell all objects are injected correctly from the FXML, but once the center panel has switched, the side buttons no longer function (Though I can click any initially and it will load.

Footnote: The code above is slightly cut down and changed for readability.

Comment: Without seeing the `fxml` for this controller (I'm assuming we're looking at a part of a controller), it's a bit hard to tell. Is there a reason why you are assigning action handlers in such an odd fashion? It's more customary to have a single method for each button's action handler which is either assigned in the `initialize()` method, or mapped via `fxml`.

Comment: I wonder why this works in the first place, since you never seem to fill the map...

Comment: It seems you are trying to set handlers on buttons that are not officially apart of the controller. I have a similar situation that I can post to give you an idea of how I handled it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I forgot to include the FXML. I'll edit it in now. Thanks for your replies. What is the reason for having single methods for each button? Wouldn't that just mean less dry code?

Comment: You can still have other methods (and invoke them from the handler methods), so there would be no reason at all to repeat yourself. And by having multiple methods you get rid of that ugly `if` statement (which will get really ugly as you increase the number of buttons).

Comment: I'll try do some debugging with that in mind Sedrick, thank you very much.

Comment: Ahh I understand. I suppose it would make the code look a lot better for no real cost, thanks for your reply.

Comment: I don't see `fooButton` or `barButton` in the FXML (or anything that has an `onAction` mapping to `handleButton`).

Comment: Updated again. I had originally changed the variables for simplicity but it seems this was a bad choice now.

Comment: OK, but as pointed out in an earlier comment, at no point do you ever populate the hash map (`buttonsPaneHMap`), so as far as we can tell no handlers are ever added to the buttons...

Comment: Well, I did have a method for that purpose, but left it out because I assumed it'd be irrelevant. Nonetheless, I hadn't called it when initialising. Still though the same issue remains, and I'm now even more perplexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took an idea from Android's playbook.
If you know how to get to the node's parent and you know the node's fx:id, you can use this approach.

The full code loads different panes into the center of a Scene depending on which button is press. The code below is a sample that show how one pane is loaded. You can get any node using this idea if you know the node's parent, the node's fx:id and the node's type for casting.

> Controller code

```
private void showSetupAccountScreen()
{
    try 
    {
        spCenterDisplay.getChildren().remove(0);//remove old display            
        BorderPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SubSetupAccount.fxml"));
        spCenterDisplay.getChildren().add(root);//add new display
        GridPane tempDisplay = (GridPane)root.getChildren().get(1);//get Parent of the nodes I will be using in this controller
        loadQWERTYKeyboard();            

        TextField tfFirstName = (TextField)findNodeByID("tfFirstName", tempDisplay.getChildren());
        TextField tfLastName = (TextField)findNodeByID("tfLastName", tempDisplay.getChildren());
        TextField tfStreetAddress = (TextField)findNodeByID("tfStreetAddress", tempDisplay.getChildren());
        TextField tfCity = (TextField)findNodeByID("tfCity", tempDisplay.getChildren());
        TextField tfState = (TextField)findNodeByID("tfState", tempDisplay.getChildren());
        TextField tfZip = (TextField)findNodeByID("tfZip", tempDisplay.getChildren());
        TextField tfInitialDepositChecking = (TextField)findNodeByID("tfInitialDepositChecking", tempDisplay.getChildren());
        TextField tfInitialDepositSavings  = (TextField)findNodeByID("tfInitialDepositSavings", tempDisplay.getChildren());
        ChoiceBox cbChecking  = (ChoiceBox)findNodeByID("cbChecking", tempDisplay.getChildren());
        cbChecking.getItems().addAll("No", "Yes");
        cbChecking.setValue("No");
        ChoiceBox cbSavings  = (ChoiceBox)findNodeByID("cbSavings", tempDisplay.getChildren());
        cbSavings.getItems().addAll("No", "Yes");
        cbSavings.setValue("No");            

        if(true)//come back and check to make sure all info is in textfields
        {
            btnLeftOne.setOnAction((event) -> {

                boolean createChecking = cbChecking.getValue().equals("Yes");
                boolean createSavings = cbSavings.getValue().equals("Yes");

                dbh.createNewAccount(tfFirstName.getText(), tfLastName.getText(), tfStreetAddress.getText(), tfCity.getText(), 
                                     tfState.getText(), tfZip.getText(), createChecking, Double.parseDouble(tfInitialDepositChecking.getText()),
                                     createSavings, Double.parseDouble(tfInitialDepositSavings.getText()));
            });
        }
        else
        {
            //create Alert 
        }

        btnRightOne.setOnAction((event) -> {
            cancelAccountCreation();
        });

        btnLeftTwo.setOnAction(null);
        btnLeftThree.setOnAction(null);
        btnLeftFour.setOnAction(null);
        btnRightTwo.setOnAction(null);
        btnRightThree.setOnAction(null);
        btnRightFour.setOnAction(null);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private void loadQWERTYKeyboard()
{
    try 
    {
        AnchorPane keyboardRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("KeyboardQWERTY.fxml"));
        System.out.println(keyboardRoot.getId());
        spBottomDisplay.getChildren().add(keyboardRoot);

        GridPane tempKeyboard = (GridPane)keyboardRoot.getChildren().get(0);

        tempKeyboard.getChildren().stream().filter((tempNode)
                -> (tempNode instanceof Button)).map((
                        tempNode) -> (Button) tempNode).forEachOrdered((tempButton) -> {
                            buttons.put(tempButton.getText().toLowerCase(), tempButton);
                        });

        apMain.setOnKeyPressed((event) -> {
            Button tempButton = buttons.get(event.getText());
            if (tempButton != null) {
                tempButton.arm();
                tempButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
            }
            else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                tempButton = buttons.get("enter");
                tempButton.arm();
                tempButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
            }
            else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE)) {
                tempButton = buttons.get("backspace");
                tempButton.arm();
                tempButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
            }
            else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SPACE)) {
                tempButton = buttons.get("space");
                tempButton.arm();
                tempButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
            }
        });

        apMain.setOnKeyReleased((event) -> {
            System.out.println();
            Button tempButton = buttons.get(event.getText());
            System.out.println("Released key text: " + event.getText());
            System.out.println("Released key code: " + event.getCode());

            if (tempButton != null) {
                tempButton.disarm();
                tempButton.setStyle("");
            }
            else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
                tempButton = buttons.get("enter");
                tempButton.disarm();
                tempButton.setStyle("");
            }
            else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.BACK_SPACE)) {
                tempButton = buttons.get("backspace");
                tempButton.disarm();
                tempButton.setStyle("");
            }
            else if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SPACE)) {
                tempButton = buttons.get("space");
                tempButton.disarm();
                tempButton.setStyle("");
            }
        });
    }
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

private Node findNodeByID(String id, ObservableList<Node> observableList)
{
    for(Node node : observableList)
    {
        if(node.getId().equals(id))
        {
            System.out.println("node found!");
            return node;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("node not found yet!");
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

In this snippet of code I use two different approaches. In the loadQWERTYKeyboard methods is one approach. In the findNodeByID is the second approach. The full code is found [here](https://github.com/sedj601/ATMFx). Working but project not complete.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to the code you posted. This answer uses the same two ideas talked about in the original answer.

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication75 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="449.0" prefWidth="564.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication75.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="btnMainBar" layoutX="76.0" layoutY="391.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Load Bar" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <Button fx:id="btnMainFoo" layoutX="419.0" layoutY="391.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Load Foo" />
      <AnchorPane fx:id="apMain" layoutX="161.0" layoutY="88.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="100.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="25.0" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

> Controller

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{    
    @FXML AnchorPane apMain;//This pane will be used to display the other two panes depending on which button is pressed.

    //Foo Pane children nodes
    Button btnFooOne, btnFooTwo;
    TextField tfFooOne, tfFooTwo;
    Label lblFoo;

    //Bar Pane children nodes
    Button btnBar;
    TextField tfBar;
    Label lblBar;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(((Button)event.getSource()).getId().equals("btnMainBar"))
        {
            loadBarPane();
        }
        else if(((Button)event.getSource()).getId().equals("btnMainFoo"))
        {
            loadFooPane();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO
    }   

    //This approach uses the findNodeByID method.
    private void loadFooPane()
    {
        try 
        {
            if(apMain.getChildren().size() > 0)
            {
                apMain.getChildren().remove(0);//if a node is loaded into apMain, remove the node.
            }

            Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Foo.fxml"));
            apMain.getChildren().add(root);//Add Foo Pane to apMain

            //Get Foo Pane's children nodes
            tfFooOne = (TextField)findNodeByID("tfFooOne", root.getChildren());
            tfFooTwo = (TextField)findNodeByID("tfFooTwo", root.getChildren());
            btnFooOne = (Button)findNodeByID("btnFooOne", root.getChildren());
            btnFooTwo = (Button)findNodeByID("btnFooTwo", root.getChildren());
            lblFoo = (Label)findNodeByID("lblFoo", root.getChildren());

            //Set Listeners

            tfFooOne.textProperty().addListener((obserValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                lblFoo.setText("new value: " + newValue);
            });

            tfFooTwo.textProperty().addListener((obserValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                lblFoo.setText("new value: " + newValue);
            });

            btnFooOne.setOnAction((event) -> {lblFoo.setText("You pressed btnFooOne");});
            btnFooTwo.setOnAction((event) -> {lblFoo.setText("You pressed btnFooTwo");});

        }
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void loadBarPane()
    {
        try
        {
            //This way is more complicate if you have more than one of the same type of node
            if(apMain.getChildren().size() > 0)
            {
                apMain.getChildren().remove(0);//if a node is loaded into apMain, remove the node.
            }
            Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Bar.fxml"));
            apMain.getChildren().add(root);//Add Foo Pane to apMain

            //Get Bar Pane's children nodes
            for(Node node : root.getChildren())
            {
                if(node instanceof Button)
                {
                    btnBar = (Button)node;
                }
                else if(node instanceof TextField)
                {
                    tfBar = (TextField)node;
                }
                else if(node instanceof Label)
                {
                    lblBar = (Label)node;
                }
            }

            //Set listeners
            tfBar.textProperty().addListener((obserValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                lblBar.setText("new value: " + newValue);
            });

            btnBar.setOnAction((event) -> {lblBar.setText("You pressed btnFooOne");});
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private Node findNodeByID(String id, ObservableList<Node> observableList)
    {
        for(Node node : observableList)
        {
            if(node.getId().equals(id))
            {
                System.out.println("node found!");
                return node;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("node not found yet!");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

> Foo FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="324.0" prefWidth="464.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="btnFooOne" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="209.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Button fx:id="btnFooTwo" layoutX="329.0" layoutY="209.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <TextField fx:id="tfFooOne" layoutX="36.0" layoutY="162.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="tfFooTwo" layoutX="281.0" layoutY="162.0" />
      <Label fx:id="lblFoo" layoutX="165.0" layoutY="39.0" text="You just loaded Foo Pane" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

> Bar FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="324.0" prefWidth="464.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="btnBar" layoutX="206.0" layoutY="186.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <TextField fx:id="tfBar" layoutX="158.0" layoutY="130.0" />
      <Label fx:id="lblBar" layoutX="160.0" layoutY="65.0" text="You just loaded Bar Pane" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, both have been helpful in learning how to structure JavaFX.           

Would you be able to expand more upon this comment?

`//This way is more complicate if you have more than one of the same type of node`

Comment: I think that I may have edited that last line while you were reading sorry, I pressed enter prematurely. The problem is coming along though!