# JavaFX switch scenes / screens / app in main BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml

Here is the problem,

I have a JavaFX application, main display element is a BorderPane.

I use the top of the BorderPane to display buttons, that will act like "navigation" buttons, and the center to display the current chosen application part.

Some solution, described on this link should do the trick :

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2598756

I'm really confused about the code, The only thing I really understand here is that it sets up some kind of changeListener on a list, supposed to hold the "selectedView".

Once the list changes, it triggers a function in the main part of the application, and this fuction SHOULD set the center element display with a new fxml file loaded.

So, I tried to implement quite the same example, only with 2 levels (main -> center) and get nothing working.

Here are the current files I created :

```
ScreenSwitcher.java
// Main class, loads the "main" fxml component

Main.fxml
// Main fxml component, BorderPane (buttons + center -empty-)

MainController.java
// Main controller, the magic should happen here

PaneOne.fxml & PaneTwo.fxml
// Children fxml, should only be displayed in the main->center element

PanelOneController.java & PaneTwoController.java
// Corresponding controllers

ViewControllerInterface.java
// An interface, as described in the given link explanation
```

https://github.com/Julo0sS/ScreenSwitcher

First, at app starting, I get this warning :

```
WARNING: Exception while evaluating select-binding [selectedView]
```

Then, when clicking on a button to switch the main display, nothing happens... I do have the console showing "CALL TO GOPANEWO" (or GOPANEONE), so it goes into the function code, but seems like the "changeListener" does not work...

Maybe I'm just wrong in the code, maybe there's a better/faster way to achieve what I'm trying, but actually, I'm just stuck on this...

Thanks for reading / help

**Update One**

Can get a part of the app working now,

The change currentView "event" is sent, and works correctly, WHEN sent by the child view itself (by click on a button in PaneOne, or PaneTwo), but does NOT work when triggered in the main view (in the top part of the borderpane, which is supposed to be a navbar)

Git repo updated with latest modifications...

Comment: The linked question is more complex than what you are trying to do: in that question (IIRC) the OP wants to change the *menu* (not just the main display) when different screens are shown. Your menu stays fixed - so you don't need this complexity. Just change the center of the border pane when the buttons are pressed - that's all you need here.

Comment: Hi @James_D yeah, I saw that he wanted something more complex, but somehow, maybe later in the app, a component within the center part should be able to do the same job as the main button, fire a new fxml loading, that's why I try to do it quite the same way as he does. By the way, actually, nothing works as expected...^^

Comment: Yes, because you are trying to observe the nested property in the controller that you are changing, so it is necessarily null when you load the new controller (and so it won't change the center...). Again, if the menu is fixed, this is much easier. If I find time I will add a solution later, but you are trying to use something that is way more complex than you need. Just try a simple approach first.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with the nested properties, where is my mistake?

Comment: The `Bindings.select(...)` is a nested property (property of a property).

Comment: so where's the trick with that part? currentViewController should be set at this point, am I wrong?

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you set the value of `currentViewController`. TBH, it just looks like you have copied code here without understanding what it is doing.

Comment: This was something I was wondering about this currentViewController (which is the currentSubMenuController in the oracle community example). I did remove this part (handleUser) because I thought it was only "side-menu" related... This is the mistake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143890/discussion-between-julo0ss-and-james-d).

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/sedj601/ATMFx).

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399207/javafx-switching-borderpanes-center-buttons-only-work-once/43413515#43413515) too.

Comment: Thanks for links, I will have a look. But the main thing I try to achieve is to : allow main display (buttons, navbar) to change display, but to allow children to do so too... Children (here, foo, bar, in your 2nd link) should be able to "tell" the main container that it has to change display... (I don't know if I'm clear...)

Comment: The buttons in foo and bar onclick just prints that they were clicked. You can make those buttons load a different view if you need to.

Comment: Yeah, I saw this, but they dont "communicate" with the main controller... they should do something that triggers a listener on the maincontroller, and the listener (just as oracle example -should-) switches the view... Not in the current view itself...

Comment: I updated the question, Can get the "child -> main" communication working, but another "Bindings" issue when view change "should be" triggered from the maincontroller itself...